# Is there a way to make multiple requests in python using an API?

Tags: python, api, search, get-request

I have been trying to figure out how to make multiple requests in python ( I am using a food API) . So far I am searching for different ingredients but would like to go a bit further and get wine recommendations with my recipes.I am not sure if this is possible but so far this is my code :

```js
import requests
from pprint import pprint

recipe_ingredients = input("What is the recipe ingredients? ")
number_recipes = input("How many recipes do you want? ")
url = 'https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/findByIngredients?ingredients={}&number={}'.format(recipe_ingredients,number_recipes)

response = requests.get(url)
print(response)

recipes = response.json()
# pprint(recipes)

for recipe in recipes:
    print(recipe['usedIngredients'])
    if len(recipe['usedIngredients']) != 0:
        title = recipe['title']
        print(title)

        ingredients = recipe['usedIngredients']
        for ingredient in ingredients:
            print(ingredient['originalString'])
        # print(ingredients)
```

I have considered implementing the following code after the last #print (ingredients) :

**paired_wine = input("What is your main ingredient?")

## output should print recommended wine for the recipe ingredient

url = ('https://api.spoonacular.com/food/wine/pairing?food={}')
response = requests.get(url)
print(response)
wine = response.json()

## pprint(wine)**

However , the console gives me the output of  once I enter my ingredient. Can anyone help me figure this out please so my output is the recommended wine, as I am new to python? Its not an issue with the API key as I enter it at the end of my url in the right format. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I get a response 200 as my output*

Comment: Very confusing.. I don't know exactly what you want. can you maybe give us the output and tell us what you want again?

Comment: it seems there is some editing failure in the question, but I really couldn't figure out, what problem you have and what is the current output. Maybe you could reedit your question, so others could understand that better?